# How to run 2005 rdlc format in visual studio 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2012, rdlc

I am bit confused here, please help me to resolve this issue.
 I had a rdlc in 2005 schema and I have install visual studio 2012 and it asked me convert the RDLC in new format I have converted. and it works all good in my local.

but we are deploying this to different deployment server which has a 2005 sql server in it. and it gives me and error

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

so I m trying to downgrade my report on my local to run 2005 rdlc format in VS 2012 but it gives me different error.
The report definition is not valid. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

how do I solve this problem so I can run 2005 format rdlc in my local and deploy on the server with sql server 205

please help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a different solution: install a newer version of [ReportViewer Runtime](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747) on your deployment server.

Comment: Hi tezzo, i ended up upgrading the reportViewer on to the deployment server. Thanks.